# Parse for iOS: Errors when trying to run the app(38 errors)

Tags: ios, facebook, parse-platform

I used Parse SDK and Facebooks. When I tried to run the app, I got 38 errors...
Any ideas as to why?
Please tell me how to solve it. I found the article about using libspl3.dylib to solve "*splite3*◯◯◯_◯◯◯", referenced from:~~.
but there is no libspl3.dylib for iOS 9. I used _sqlite3.tdb. But I could not solve it.
(I'm sorry that my English is poor.)

> Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:   "_sqlite3_column_count",
>   referenced from:
>         -[PFSQLiteDatabaseResult columnNameToIndexMap] in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabaseResult.o)   "_sqlite3_column_name", referenced
>   from:
>         -[PFSQLiteDatabaseResult columnNameToIndexMap] in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabaseResult.o)   "_sqlite3_column_type", referenced
>   from:
>         -[PFSQLiteDatabaseResult objectForColumnIndex:] in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabaseResult.o)
>         -[PFSQLiteDatabaseResult columnIndexIsNull:] in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabaseResult.o)   "_sqlite3_column_blob", referenced
>   from:
>         -[PFSQLiteDatabaseResult dataForColumnIndex:] in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabaseResult.o)   "_sqlite3_bind_blob", referenced
>   from:
>         -[PFSQLiteDatabase _bindObject:toColumn:inStatement:] in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabase.o)   "_sqlite3_bind_null", referenced from:
>         -[PFSQLiteDatabase _bindObject:toColumn:inStatement:] in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabase.o)   "_sqlite3_bind_double", referenced from:
>         -[PFSQLiteDatabase _bindObject:toColumn:inStatement:] in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabase.o)
>        (maybe you meant: _fbsdkdfl_sqlite3_bind_double)   "_sqlite3_bind_int64", referenced from:
>         -[PFSQLiteDatabase _bindObject:toColumn:inStatement:] in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabase.o)   "_sqlite3_bind_parameter_count",
>   referenced from:
>         -[PFSQLiteDatabase _executeQueryAsync:withArgumentsInArray:cachingEnabled:] in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabase.o)
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy", referenced from:
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
>   "_FBTokenInformationUserFBIDKey", referenced from:
>         -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy facebookId] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
>         -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy setFacebookId:] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
>   "_FBTokenInformationExpirationDateKey", referenced from:
>         -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy cacheTokenInformation:] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
>         -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy expirationDate] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
>         -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy setExpirationDate:] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
>   "_sqlite3_column_int", referenced from:
>         -[PFSQLiteDatabaseResult intForColumnIndex:] in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabaseResult.o)
>        (maybe you meant: _fbsdkdfl_sqlite3_column_int)   "_SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags", referenced from:
>         ___54-[PFReachability _startMonitoringReachabilityWithURL:]_block_invoke in Parse(PFReachability.o)   "_SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback",
>   referenced from:
>         -[PFEventuallyQueue _stopMonitoringNetworkReachability] in Parse(PFEventuallyQueue.o)
>         -[PFReachability dealloc] in Parse(PFReachability.o)
>         ___54-[PFReachability _startMonitoringReachabilityWithURL:]_block_invoke in Parse(PFReachability.o)   "_sqlite3_clear_bindings", referenced from:
>         ___34-[PFDateFormatter dateFromString:]_block_invoke in Parse(PFDateFormatter.o)   "_AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID",
>   referenced from:
>         +[PFPushUtilities playAudioWithName:] in Parse(PFPushUtilities.o)
>        (maybe you meant: _fbsdkdfl_AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID)   "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy", referenced from:
>         _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
>   "_AudioServicesPlaySystemSound", referenced from:
>         +[PFPushUtilities playAudioWithName:] in Parse(PFPushUtilities.o)
>         +[PFPushUtilities playVibrate] in Parse(PFPushUtilities.o)
>        (maybe you meant: _fbsdkdfl_AudioServicesPlaySystemSound)   "_sqlite3_bind_text", referenced from:
>         ___34-[PFDateFormatter dateFromString:]_block_invoke in Parse(PFDateFormatter.o)
>         -[PFSQLiteDatabase _bindObject:toColumn:inStatement:] in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabase.o)
>        (maybe you meant: _fbsdkdfl_sqlite3_bind_text)   "_sqlite3_column_int64", referenced from:
>         ___34-[PFDateFormatter dateFromString:]_block_invoke in Parse(PFDateFormatter.o)
>         -[PFSQLiteDatabaseResult longForColumnIndex:] in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabaseResult.o)   "_sqlite3_errmsg", referenced from:
>         -[PFSQLiteDatabase _errorWithErrorCode:] in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabase.o)
>        (maybe you meant: _fbsdkdfl_sqlite3_errmsg)   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBRequest", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSession", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)
>   "_FBTokenInformationTokenKey", referenced from:
>         -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy accessToken] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
>         -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy setAccessToken:] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
>   "_sqlite3_step", referenced from:
>         ___34-[PFDateFormatter dateFromString:]_block_invoke in Parse(PFDateFormatter.o)
>         -[PFSQLiteDatabaseResult step] in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabaseResult.o)
>        (maybe you meant: _fbsdkdfl_sqlite3_step)   "_sqlite3_column_double", referenced from:
>         ___34-[PFDateFormatter dateFromString:]_block_invoke in Parse(PFDateFormatter.o)
>         -[PFSQLiteDatabaseResult doubleForColumnIndex:] in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabaseResult.o)
>        (maybe you meant: _fbsdkdfl_sqlite3_column_double)   "_sqlite3_open", referenced from:
>         -[PFDateFormatter init] in Parse(PFDateFormatter.o)
>         ___29-[PFSQLiteDatabase openAsync]_block_invoke in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabase.o)
>        (maybe you meant: _fbsdkdfl_sqlite3_open_v2)   "_sqlite3_reset", referenced from:
>         ___34-[PFDateFormatter dateFromString:]_block_invoke in Parse(PFDateFormatter.o)
>         -[PFSQLiteStatement reset] in Parse(PFSQLiteStatement.o)
>        (maybe you meant: _fbsdkdfl_sqlite3_reset)   "_SCNetworkReachabilitySetDispatchQueue", referenced from:
>         -[PFEventuallyQueue _stopMonitoringNetworkReachability] in Parse(PFEventuallyQueue.o)
>         -[PFReachability dealloc] in Parse(PFReachability.o)
>         ___54-[PFReachability _startMonitoringReachabilityWithURL:]_block_invoke in Parse(PFReachability.o)   "_sqlite3_column_bytes", referenced from:
>         -[PFSQLiteDatabaseResult dataForColumnIndex:] in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabaseResult.o)   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBAppCall",
>   referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)
>   "_sqlite3_column_text", referenced from:
>         -[PFSQLiteDatabaseResult stringForColumnIndex:] in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabaseResult.o)
>        (maybe you meant: _fbsdkdfl_sqlite3_column_text)   "_sqlite3_finalize", referenced from:
>         -[PFDateFormatter dealloc] in Parse(PFDateFormatter.o)
>         -[PFSQLiteDatabase _executeQueryAsync:withArgumentsInArray:cachingEnabled:] in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabase.o)
>         -[PFSQLiteStatement close] in Parse(PFSQLiteStatement.o)
>        (maybe you meant: _fbsdkdfl_sqlite3_finalize)   "_SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName", referenced from:
>         ___54-[PFReachability _startMonitoringReachabilityWithURL:]_block_invoke in Parse(PFReachability.o)   "_sqlite3_close", referenced from:
>         -[PFDateFormatter dealloc] in Parse(PFDateFormatter.o)
>         ___30-[PFSQLiteDatabase closeAsync]_block_invoke in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabase.o)
>        (maybe you meant: _fbsdkdfl_sqlite3_close)   "_sqlite3_prepare_v2", referenced from:
>         -[PFDateFormatter init] in Parse(PFDateFormatter.o)
>         -[PFSQLiteDatabase _executeQueryAsync:withArgumentsInArray:cachingEnabled:] in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabase.o)
>        (maybe you meant: _fbsdkdfl_sqlite3_prepare_v2) ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64 clang: error: linker command failed with
>   exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: `ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64`

Comment: Thank you for answering.
But I don`t understand how to solve.
Do you have any good ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You need to link a new, but not so new, framework to your project.

- libsqlite3.tbd

My guess is you will also have to substitute the following two frameworks as well:

- lib.1.1.3.tbd
- libstdc++.6.tbd

FYI, the .tbd extension frameworks are new "text-based stub libraries", that provide a much more compact version of their ancestor libraries for use in the SDK, which in return helps to significantly reduce download size.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering , and the detailed explanation.
I did, and I could solve 8 errors!

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when Xcode 6 launched.  There is a couple of work arounds that you may be able to find, but I simply had to wait for Parse to update their API to support the new Xcode release.  I know this doesn't help right at this moment, but they are generally really good at keeping up.  I would say you should be up and running within a week at the absolute maximum.  As a role of thumb, I stick with the previous version until Parse updates.

Answer (score 0):

I had almost the same errors during the installation and for me the Bolts framework was outdated too (Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX, Static folder, Objective-C). So here's what I did.

1) Added these in Xcode to linked frameworks and libraries:

- libsqlite3.tbd
- SystemConfiguration.framework
- AudioToolbox.framework

2) Located Bolts.framework in Finder and moved it to trash. Browsed to [Facebook Developer page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/componentsdks) and downloaded the latest SDK from there. Grabbed the compiled Bolts.framework-file and added it back to the same place where I deleted it.

Hopes it works for you too.